# How to determine the corresponding language of a grammar?

Tags: semantics, context-free-grammar, syntactic-sugar

I have the following grammar that uses center embedded recursion. However, it has two cases using an or:
`S-> aSbbb | aSbb | ϵ` where ϵ is an empty set.
Is there a way to generate a comprehensive mathematical formula (Language) that determines that grammar?

Comment: Might be my ignorance showing, but a grammar is the best way I know to communicate a [language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language), and you have the grammar.  Not sure what you're asking for here.  Are you hoping to convert your grammar into a different form?

Comment: I meant that given the following grammar (written in code above) how could we write its corresponding language.

Comment: Basically you're asking "What is the word for an apple?" "Uh, apple." "No, but what's the word for it?" "No seriously, the word is apple".  Your grammar _is_ how we would write the corresponding language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar is the "comprehensive mathematical formula". :) However, in the current case, it is easy to give an alternate description. Your grammar will generate strings of the form

```
a^nb^m
```

where `s^i` stands for "repeat the substring `s` `i` times", and

```
2n <= m <= 3n
```

`n` can also be 0 (empty string).